# Randomly create images in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games

I'm  new to programming, and I'm trying to make a simple cars game using pygame, everything works fine until I tried to make cars appear randomly from the opposite direction, I succeeded in making rectangles appear randomly, but when I wanted to use a sprite of rectangles it didn't work, the errors I got are :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/saifo/PycharmProjects/untitled/gamev2.py", line 241, in 
>       game_intro()
>     File "C:/Users/saifo/PycharmProjects/untitled/gamev2.py", line 158, in game_intro
>       button("START",150,450,100,50,red,green,'Play')
>     File "C:/Users/saifo/PycharmProjects/untitled/gamev2.py", line 89, in button
>       game_loop()
>     File "C:/Users/saifo/PycharmProjects/untitled/gamev2.py", line 190, in game_loop
>       truck(tx,ty)
>     File "C:/Users/saifo/PycharmProjects/untitled/gamev2.py", line 32, in truck
>       gameDisplay.blit(truck(tx,ty))
>     File "C:/Users/saifo/PycharmProjects/untitled/gamev2.py", line 32, in truck
>       gameDisplay.blit(truck(tx,ty))
>     File "C:/Users/saifo/PycharmProjects/untitled/gamev2.py", line 32, in truck
>       gameDisplay.blit(truck(tx,ty))
>     [Previous line repeated 992 more times]
>   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

and here is my code,

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load('C:/Users/saifo/Downloads/Documents/sprites/khaled.mp3')
crash_sound= pygame.mixer.Sound('C:/Users/saifo/Downloads/Documents/sprites/crash.wav')
height=600
width=800
white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
red=(255,0,0)
green=(0,255,0)
bleu=(0,0,255)

#x_change=0
gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Racing')
clock =pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/saifo/Downloads/Documents/sprites/viper.png')
backImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/saifo/Downloads/Documents/sprites/back.png')
truck = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/saifo/Downloads/Documents/sprites/truck.png')
carImg = pygame.transform.scale(carImg,(100,100))
truck = pygame.transform.scale(truck,(100,100))
backImg=pygame.transform.scale(backImg,(800,600))
carWidth =100
pause = False
pygame.display.set_icon(carImg)

def truck(tx,ty):
    gameDisplay.blit(truck(tx,ty))

# def things (thingx,thingy,thingw,thingh,color):
#     pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,color,[thingx,thingy,thingw,thingh])

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))

def dodged(count):
    font =pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
    text =font.render("Dodged :" + str(count),True,white)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def text_objects(text,font):
    textSurface=font.render(text,True,black)
    return  textSurface,textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',80)
    textSurf,textRect = text_objects(text,largeText)
    textRect.center=((width/2),(height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf,textRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)
    game_loop()

def crash():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(crash_sound)
    message_display('you crashed')

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,a,i,action=None):


    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #print(click,mouse)
    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, a, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0]==1 and action!=None:
            if action=='Play':
                game_loop()
            elif action=='Quit':
                pygame.QUIT
                quit()
            elif action=='Resume':
                unpause()

    smalltext = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 25)
    textsurf ,textrect=text_objects(msg,smalltext)
    textrect.center=((x+(w/2)),(y+(h/2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(textsurf,textrect)
    pygame.display.update()

def unpause():
    global pause
    pause = False
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()


def paused():
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    while pause:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type== pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 80)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("PAUSED", largeText)
        textRect.center = ((width / 2), (height / 2))
        gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,green,(150,450,100,50))
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,bleu,(550,450,100,50))

        button("RESUME",150,450,120,50,red,green,'Resume')
        button("QUIT",550,450,110,50,red,bleu,'Quit')



        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type== pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 80)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Formula 00", largeText)
        textRect.center = ((width / 2), (height / 2))
        gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,green,(150,450,100,50))
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,bleu,(550,450,100,50))

        button("START",150,450,100,50,red,green,'Play')
        button("QUIT",550,450,100,50,red,bleu,'Quit')



        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)



def game_loop():
    global  pause
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    x_change=0
    x=(width*0.45)
    y=(height*0.8)
    tx=random.randrange(0,width)
    ty=-100
    thing_startx=random.randrange(0,width)
    thing_starty=-100
    thing_speed=7
    thingw=60
    thingh=60
    dodge=0
    gameExit= False


    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type== pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                if event.key==pygame.K_p:
                    pause=True
                    paused()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or  event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0



        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.blit(backImg,(0,0))
        truck(tx,ty)
        ty+=thing_speed
        # things(thing_startx,thing_starty,thingw,thingh,red)
        # thing_starty +=thing_speed
        car(x,y)
        dodged(dodge)
        x += x_change

        if x > width - carWidth or x < 0:
            crash()

        if ty > height:
            ty = 0 - 100
            tx = random.randrange(0, width)
            dodge+=1


        if y < ty+100:
            if x > tx and x < tx + 100 or x + carWidth>tx and x + carWidth < tx+100:
                crash()


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Just some general remarks on your code since you're new to programming: You should try to make you code easy to understand. In this case this could mean copying the functions to a separate [module](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html). Or even better learn [how to use classes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes) and locate some functionality elsewhere. This will make your future work a lot easier as your code starts to grow.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling functions between methods and that is very bad!

possible answer:

[Pygame - RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476939/pygame-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-calling-a-python-o)

Good luck!

Comment: I'd rephrase the answer. The problem is that the `truck` function recurses, that means it *calls itself*, and it calls itself until Python's recursion limit (of 1000 recursions) is exceeded. Recursion is not bad by default and can be very useful, but a function can't recurse infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

The `RecursionError` is caused by the `truck` function which calls itself until Python's recursion limit is exceeded. Also, the `truck` surface/image and the `truck` function must not have the same name (the `def truck(tx, ty):` line overrides the image variable).

It looks to me like you just wanted to blit the `truck` surface in this function, so I suggest to rename it to `blit_truck` and fix the code inside:

```
def blit_truck(tx,ty):
    gameDisplay.blit(truck, (tx, ty))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys , actually , the mistake was something dumb , i was missing a comma , in  `gameDisplay.blit(truck , (tx,ty))` , instead i wrote  `gameDisplay.blit(truck(tx,ty))`, now it works. 
thanks again.